# Cannot achieve nice spacing in list items in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

I am trying to achieve the best spacing between `items` in a `beamer` presentation. I am using

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Short Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}%[noitemsep]
\item Micromegas Telescope
\item Laboratory Set-up
\begin{itemize}
\item Signal to Noise Ratio Optimization
\item Double Spectrum Issue
\end{itemize}
\item Tracker Configuration
\begin{itemize}
\item High Voltage
\item Resistivity
\item Front End Chip
\end{itemize}
\item Software
\begin{itemize}
\item Data Acquisition Software
\item Preliminary Data Visualisation
\end{itemize}
\item Data Analysis
\begin{itemize}
\item Characterisation of the tracking system
\item $1M\Omega/\Box\;Vs\;100k\Omega/\Box$
\item Position Scan
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Micromegas Telescope}

\begin{frame}
Good Morning Vietnam!!!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I run the previous code I am missing some items.
I tried to use `noitemsep` and `nolistsep` but it isn't working.
I also used `paralist` and `compactitem` but again it wasn't working.
I also tried with

```
\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.1\baselineskip}
```

but the fact that I am having nested lists doesn't produce a nice output not matter how hard I play with spaces...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use packages which change the list definitions: They will break the overlay capabilities of the lists in beamer. You can copy the original list values from `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` and adapt them (see below). But you will gain only a bit space. Imho it is better to reconsider the content of the frame. A "short introduction" shouldn't be so long. Or use a two column layout with a smaller font.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Short Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}%[noitemsep]
\item Micromegas Telescope
\item Laboratory Set-up
\begin{itemize}
\item Signal to Noise Ratio Optimization
\item Double Spectrum Issue
\end{itemize}
\item Tracker Configuration
\begin{itemize}
\item High Voltage
\item Resistivity
\item Front End Chip
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\begin{frame}
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \topsep 0pt
            \parsep 0pt
            \itemsep0pt}
\let\@listI\@listi
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \topsep    0pt
              \parsep    0pt
              \itemsep   0pt}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \topsep    0pt
              \parsep    0pt
              \itemsep   0pt}
\frametitle{Short Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}%[noitemsep]
\item Micromegas Telescope
\item Laboratory Set-up
\begin{itemize}
\item Signal to Noise Ratio Optimization
\item Double Spectrum Issue
\end{itemize}
\item Tracker Configuration
\begin{itemize}
\item High Voltage
\item Resistivity
\item Front End Chip
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is partially working...In the case of a few bullet points it makes some effect, however this is not the case when I use all my bullet points...The font size, could be an idea, but I wanted this to be the solution if nothing else will work.

Comment: I also tried with `multicols` but the output isn't quite pretty... It is working well if I use `11pt` font size.